# How to add edge to edge overlay on the top of recyclerView cell?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Following is my xml of my recyclerview cell

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">

        <com.company.voice.view.font.CustomFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/left_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/nameHintGrey"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

        <com.company.voice.view.font.CustomFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/right_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/nameHintGrey"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.company.voice.view.custom.UserProfileView
            android:id="@+id/user_right_image"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <com.company.voice.view.font.CustomFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/message_right_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/user_right_image"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/root_container" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/multi_select_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/empty_view"
    android:background="@color/multiSelectChatBG"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_selectchat" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Issue: I want to fill this green background to the whole cell of recycler view. Height of the every cell vary based on the number of lines of the textview. I have tried many things but failed.

Following is the current output

[image: Current Output]

Expected output is below

[image: Expected output]

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: just use a layout over it (item layout) make the it gone and visible upon clicking..

Comment: Currently I am playing with the visibility of “multi_select_container”, but it’s not working as height of that green overlay is not filling up the cell’s height. (Attached the current output in the question)

Comment: Can u add your colour changing Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreground color will be easy as well as saves extra level of container overdraw
Follow this steps or search for it

http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/07/17/adding-a-foreground-selector-to-a-view/

or mine test version
https://gist.github.com/parthdave93/1b1f6871053a575e0e19d2c17eaf4514

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get your root_container in ViewHolder and then change it's background in onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.rootContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}

public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private RelativeLayout rootContainer;

    public MainViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        rootContainer = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.root_container);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

You could put view on the bottom of your layout:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/overlay_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transprentGreen"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and then change it's size in onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.rootContainer.getLayoutParams();
    holder.overlayView.setLayoutParams(params);
}

public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private RelativeLayout rootContainer;
    private View overlayView;

    public MainViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        rootContainer = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.root_container);
        overlayView = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.overlay_view);
    }
}
```

Comment: As per requirement, I have to show that green color with tick on the top of root_container. So changing the background of root_container won’t help.

Comment: Didn't notice it was supposed to be on top, updated my answer.